# Error al correr un proyecto con tomcat 8

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, java-8, spring-tool-suite, spring-security

Cuando trato de levantar mi proyecto y pongo la direccion localhost:8080/SpringSep me sale el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que da en el log

```
      feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
      ADVERTENCIA: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:SpringSep' did not find a matching property.
           feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
           INFORMACIÓN: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.41
           feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
           INFORMACIÓN: Server built:          Jan 18 2017 22:19:39 UTC
           feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
           INFORMACIÓN: Server number:         8.0.41.0
           feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
           INFORMACIÓN: OS Name:               Linux
           feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
           INFORMACIÓN: OS Version:            4.4.0-62-generic
           feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
           INFORMACIÓN: Architecture:          amd64
           feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
           INFORMACIÓN: Java Home:             /home/jdiaz/dev/apps/sts-bundle/sts-3.8.3.RELEASE/jre
           feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
           INFORMACIÓN: JVM Version:           1.8.0_101-b13
           feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
           INFORMACIÓN: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
           feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
           INFORMACIÓN: CATALINA_BASE:         /home/jdiaz/Carpeta sin título/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
           feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
           INFORMACIÓN: CATALINA_HOME:         /home/jdiaz/apache-tomcat-8.0.41
            feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
            INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/home/jdiaz/Carpeta sin título/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0
           feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
           INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/home/jdiaz/apache-tomcat-8.0.41
           feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
           INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=/home/jdiaz/Carpeta sin título/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps
           feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
           INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/home/jdiaz/apache-tomcat-8.0.41/endorsed
           feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
            INFORMACIÓN: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
            feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
            INFORMACIÓN: La biblioteca nativa de Apache Tomcat basada en ARP que permite un rendimiento óptimo en entornos de desarrollo no ha sido hallada en java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
             feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
             INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
             feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
             INFORMACIÓN: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
             feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
             INFORMACIÓN: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
             feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
             INFORMACIÓN: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
             feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
             INFORMACIÓN: Initialization processed in 1046 ms
             feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
             INFORMACIÓN: Arrancando servicio Catalina
             feb 06, 2017 9:02:42 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
             INFORMACIÓN: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.41
              feb 06, 2017 9:02:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
             INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
             feb 06, 2017 9:02:43 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
             INFORMACIÓN: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
              feb 06, 2017 9:02:43 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
               INFORMACIÓN: Server startup in 574 ms
```

el cual no entiendo porque sale eso si el viernes se levanto bien. me podrian ayudar y tambien decirme que codigo tengo que subir.

Comment: Hola Jose. Te recomiendo poner un titulo mas decriptivo.. "no levanta" no es muy tecnico. Ademas, puedes sustituir la imagen por el texto del error?   Un saludo!

Comment: Para depurar problemas en tomcat, se necesita el bootlog de tomcat, especialmente cuando usas spring. Un 404 no ayuda mucho en encontrar el error.

Comment: Comprueba que tienes tu aplicación desplegada en /home/jdiaz/apache-tomcat-8.0.41/webapps

Comment: @pablo dentro de la carpeta webapps no se encuentra la aplicacion, ya habia revisado eso anteriormente

Comment: Pues entonces, salvo que hayas configurado una ruta alternativa de despliegue, es normal que no puedes entrar a la aplicación, ya que el Tomcat no la encuentra.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que copiar la aplicación, ya sea en un archivo War o desplegada, al directorio `webapps` del tomcat.
De manera alternativa, puedes configurar una ruta alternativa de despliegue. Para ello, en la carpeta `conf/Catalina/localhost/` del tomcat, crea un fichero `SpringSep.xml` con el contenido:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="/rutaATuAplicacionDesplegada" path="/SpringSep"/>
```

Así, si tu aplicación, ya compilada, está por ejemplo en `/home/jdiaz/SpringSep`, y el directorio que contiene la parte web con el html, carpeta `WEB-INF/classes`, etc, se llama `build` el SpringSep.xml sería:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context docBase="/home/jdiaz/SpringSep/build" path="/SpringSep"/>
```

Comment: con respecto a la direccion de la carpeta, solo tengo hasta conf. lo que es Catalina/localhost no existe

Comment: puedes crear la carpeta sin problemas, con la C de Catalina en mayúscula, eso sí.

Comment: @JoseDiaz si esta respuesta resolvió tu problema, deberías aceptarla pulsando en el ✔ que encontrarás en la parte superior izquierda de la misma.